# Objective-C – Understanding protocol references

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, protocols

```
// 1.    
TestViewController <TestViewControllerProtocol> *testVC = [TestViewController new];

// 2.
TestViewController *testVC = [TestViewController new];
```

1. What are the differences between the above references?
2. When would it be preferable to use the first one over the second one?

TestViewController.h

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <TestViewControllerProtocol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Difference: Both are of type `TestViewController` while only the first one implements the protocol `TestViewControllerProtocol`.
2. The first is only needed when that class does not explicitly conform to that protocol and you need to send messages to that object defined in that protocol. Not specifying the protocol and subsequently sending messages would result in a warning or error.

One possible scenario is that you have a superclass `TestViewController` with multiple subclasses where only a couple of them actually implement that protocol. If you have some code that uses two of those subclasses that both implement the protocol you can easily store a reference to them using the second option.

Comment: 1. Addendum, as you can see in the interface `TestViewController` always implements `TestViewControllerProtocol` so I would say even if 2 doesn't reference that protocol it still implements it?

Comment: @PeterWarbo: then there is no difference

Comment: So the first one is a way declaring that it conforms to the protocol without it actually doing so in the interface?

Comment: If the interface does not declare it but the variable type declares it, then yes. But I would argue that this is an anti-pattern.